# How to use own c# class or DLL in docusign workflow

Tags: docusignapi

I'm new in docusign.
Currently I'm working on Form development etc..
Can someone tell me where in docusign in Workflow diagram can I create or use own c# class or DLL.
Currently in a calculation stage we are creating many c# functions for field calculation but it must be there an option to use object oriented programming?
Thank you for any help, clue!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a Nuget package directly, that is found either using Nuget Package Manager or directly - https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/

Or, you can clone [this repo](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) and build it yourself and add it as a project in your solution.

If you want to see some code that is using it and try it out - go to https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp.